# Changing a node alias to reuse his old url programmatically without be still redirected to the node page

Tags: 7, path-aliases, redirection

I'm on a old site on drupal 7.
I have a node with alias `/url`. Now I need to manage that page url programmatically, so I create an item in a custom module using `hook_menu()` in this way:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function MYMODULE_menu() {
  $items = [];

  $items['url'] = [
    'title' => 'New Title',
    'page callback' => 'MYMODULE_url_callback',
    'access callback' => TRUE,
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
  ];

  return $items;
}
```

In the previous node I've changed the alias to `/url-old` but when I go to the page `/url` I've been redirected to `/url-old` and can't reach the new page.

Where is still referenced the relation between `node/<nid>` and his old alias `/url`?

I've the module [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) installed. In the aliases list the `/url` link is no more present.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look for a redirect on the Redirect config screen, */admin/config/search/redirect*. Or Via admin toolbar: Manage > Configuration > Search and metadata > URL redirects. Edit: Woops, these paths are for D8/D9, but the idea is the same.

Comment: Thanks @sonfd! It was not Pathauto but redirects configuration. It resolves :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found where are defined all node's redirects:

> Configuration > Search and metadata > URL aliases.

Needs to remove all occurrence for the new url before to reach the page programmatically.